# Frameworks/plugins useful for an ajax-based single-page-app with an ASP.NET MVC 3 backend

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-3

We're making a single-page app, where actions in the UI (e.g. clicking a node in a tree) will update parts of the UI by retrieving data with ajax-calls.

Does anyone have any tips or recommendations for javascript frameworks that will make the following easier:

- Updating the URL to show what you're looking at (e.g. http://example.com/#user/edit/321)
- Parsing an URL like that to bring up the same page from a bookmark or link.
- Updating parts of the UI based on actions in a different part. I'm thinking some sort of event model where actions can publish an event (eg "navigation_changed" with a payload `{"type":"user", "action":"edit", "id":"321"}`) and other parts of the UI can pick this up to update bread-crumbs, highlight navigation and load content.
- A good way to "ajaxify" a web-form that works with ASP.NET MVC3. We'd like to take as much  advantage as possible of the features in MVC3 like modelbinders, validation, razor views, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions so far. On other channels I've been recommended knockout.js and JavaScriptMVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to look at [jquery-bbq](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-bbq) plugin.

Comment: Backbone looks like it´s too heavyweight for our use. We already have a lot of structure server side and due to other constraints we won´t be moving that much of the app client side. In our case the bbq-plugin seems like a good choice together with some other components. Thanks for your help!

Comment: We'll also be using knockout.js for the client models. This is due to familiarity with the MVVM model and good track record and documentation for use with ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 3):

I would totally use http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/ backbone.js for that

**Edit:** Examples >> https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/downloads

Comment: You do have to rewrite Backbone.Sync to make it take advantage of ASP.NET MVC 3 though.

Answer (score 1):

I used the history.js library ([https://github.com/browserstate/history.js](http://github.com/browserstate/history.js)) to ajaxify my page, though I'm still trying to figure out the best way to implement my controllers, and how to build up my partial views.

E.g. When user clicks an href with "~/Home/Index/", it gets rewritten to "/Home/Index" page and an ajax request is done to the Home controller and Index method so I can return a partial view and all is fine... but, when you press F5 in browser it actually goes through the ASP.NET MVC routing engine, and also returns the partial view, which breaks the page...?!

Comment: You could use HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest() to return the appropriate view...